# Does Angular1.4 $http include a promise already in the http get? Or do I make my own

Tags: angularjs, promise

I'm a bit confused, the more I read resources online about `$q` and `$http` the more my head spins. So if I do a `$http.get` call does that not include a promise? Or do I bring `$q` in?

Comment: As shown [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#get) $http.get returns a promise.

Comment: You would bring $q in anyway if somewhere in the chain you want to throw an exception via $q.reject()

Answer (score 1):

It is built on $q and returns a promise. See the docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

And the example there:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
});
```

$http.get is just a convenience method on the above.

Answer (score 0):

> The $http API is based on the deferred/promise APIs exposed by the $q
>   service. While for simple usage patterns this doesn't matter much, for
>   advanced usage it is important to familiarize yourself with these APIs
>   and the guarantees they provide.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Meaning that the `$http.get` will return a promise anyway. No need nesting your own `$q` approach. Just return the `$http` invoke.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the following link

https://www.peterbe.com/plog/promises-with-$http

This service ($http.get()) will return promise  as success callback and error callback...so this function itself returns promise. You just have to handle it

Comment: $http is also a part of the link just copy  the entire link for reference

Answer (score 0):

$http.get call does that not include a promise? The Answer is Yes, you can return a promise or resolve the promise with $http

Returning a promise from $http.get

```
getData: function() {
    return $http.get('some url'); // you can resolve this promise later
                                  // using (then)
}
```

So later in your code you can resolve the above promise like this

```
...

myService.getData().then(function(response) {
    // do something with response
}).catch()
```

Resolve the promise inline

```
getData: function() {
    $http.get('some url').then(function(response) {
        // do something with response
     }).catch()
}
```